# Why does Pandas not come with an option to use .apply in place?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I like to think every design decision is made for a reason. A lot of pandas functions (e.g. `df.drop` , `df.rename` `df.replace`) come with a parameter, `inplace`. If you set it to `True`, instead of returning a new dataframe, pandas modifies the dataframe, well,  *in place*. No surprises here ;).

However, I often find my self using `df.apply` in combination with lambda expression to do somewhat more complex operations on columns. Consider the following example:

Say I have text data that needs to be pre-processed for sentiment analysis. I would use:

```
def remove_punctuation(text):
    no_punct = "".join([c for c in text if c not in string.punctuation])
    return no_punct
```

And then adapt my column as follows:

```
df['text'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: remove_punctuation(x))
```

I recently noticed that .apply *does not* have an argument `inplace=True`. Since this function is mostly used to update dataframes, why is such an argument not available? What would be a rationale behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pandas.DataFrame.apply` and `pandas.Series.apply` both returns a `Series` either from a `DataFrame` or a `Series`. In your example you apply it to a `Series` and `inplace` might make sense there. However there are other applications where it wouldn't.

For example, with `df` being:

```
   col1  col2
0     1     3
1     2     4
```

Doing:

```
s = df.apply(lambda x: x.col1 + x.col2, axis=1)
```

Would return a `Series` which has different type and shape than the original `DataFrame`.
In this case an `inplace` argument wouldn't make much sense.

I think `pandas` devs wanted to enforce consistency between `pandas.DataFrame.apply` and `pandas.Series.apply`, avoiding confusion generated by having an `inplace` argument in `pandas.Series.apply` only.